# The evolution of observables in the Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, superposition, time-evolution, quantum-states

Suppose that a system $S$ undergoes the following time-evolution:

$t_{1} \rightarrow t_{2}: |x_{a}\rangle \rightarrow \sum c_{i}|x_{i}\rangle$,

where $|x_{a}\rangle$ and each of $|x_{i}\rangle$ is a position eigenstate.

How is this process described in the Heisenberg picture? My trouble lies in the fact that $\sum c_{i}|x_{i}\rangle$ is (generally) not an eigenstate of the position operator. The operator (say, $O$) of which $\sum c_{i}|x_{i}\rangle$ is an eigenstate is (generally) not even an Hermitian operator, so the position operator would not be able to unitarily evolve into $O$. Then how is the state of $S$ at $t_{2}$ in the Schrodinger picture related to the (time-evolved) operator (observable) at $t_{2}$ in the Heisenberg picture?

Comment: Have you illustrated the harmonic oscillator in this picture?

Comment: I guess it could be an harmonic oscillator, but I just had a general situation in mind where a system evolves unitarily after a measurement is performed at $t_{1}$.

Comment: I fear you are misunderstanding something. The is all about trivial changes of equivalent bases. That's why I invited you to explicitly review the oscillator, that is so simple to not allow any confusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these types of problems, the phrase I always come back to is "expectation values don't care what picture we are in". This leads one to write
\begin{align}
\left ( \left < \psi | e^{\frac{i H t}{\hbar}} \right ) O \left ( e^{\frac{-i H t}{\hbar}} | \psi \right > \right ) = \left < \psi | \left ( e^{\frac{i H t}{\hbar}} O e^{\frac{-i H t}{\hbar}} \right ) | \psi \right >.
\end{align}
The left hand side has brackets which separate states from operators in the Schroedinger picture. The right hand side has brackets which separate states from operators in the Heisenberg picture. So the latter says that any operator (including the position operator) is evolved unitarily by $H$.

This notation helps in your example because $\sum_i c_i \left | x_i \right >$ will have to just be $e^{\frac{-i H t}{\hbar}} \left | x_a \right >$ for the evolution to be valid. The eigenstate of $x$ has therefore become an eigenstate of $e^{\frac{-i H t}{\hbar}} x e^{\frac{i H t}{\hbar}}$ which is Hermitian. You'd have to be given a Hamiltonian and coefficients $c_i$ which are incompatible with each other for this not to be the case.

**Update**

An arbitrary state $\left | \psi \right >$ is an eigenstate of the "observable" $\left | \psi \right > \left < \psi \right |$ (and many others). However, it may well be the case that these operators aren't easy to interpret. For a fixed observable (something we enjoy dealing with, say position) it is certainly the case that the system not being in an eigenstate of it is ubiquitous.

If we say that a state cannot be evolved unitarily from an eigenstate of position, that's equivalent to saying that it's not an eigenstate of $e^{\frac{-i H t}{\hbar}} x e^{\frac{i H t}{\hbar}}$ for any $t$. But there is nothing wrong with such a state. In the language of wavefunctions, it's just something that never looks like a delta function no matter how much we evolve forwards or backwards.

Maybe an analogy for an operator with a discrete spectrum will help.
\begin{equation}
\psi(x, 0) = \begin{cases}
cx, & 0 < x < L/2 \\ c(L - x), & L/2 < x < L \\ 0, & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is a perfectly good initial state for the infinite square well. However, it never becomes an energy eigenstate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This makes sense. But then, what about the cases in which (i) a system is in a superposition of multiple eigenstates of an observable and (ii) the whole system itself is not in an eigenstate of any observable? Such a state (which I'd like to call a 'proper' superposition, unless there is already a term for it) certainly obtains ubiquitously, right? But how can such a state could be unitarily evolved from an eigenstate of an observable in the Heisenberg picture?

Comment: @Conner Behan I've just seen the updated part, thanks. Regarding the update: does it mean that if a system S is in a state $\Psi$ and $\Psi$ is not an eigenstate of any Hermitian operator, S could not have been measured previously? Equivalently, if S was measured at some point in the past, then $\Psi$ *must* be an eigenstate of some observable (however the observable is complex and difficult to measure)?

Comment: But isn't it possible that we measure the position of a particle at $t_{0}$ and the state of the particle evolves into a superposition of position eigenstates, which itself is not an eigenstate of ant observable? Is such a scenario simply impossible?

Comment: Every vector in a Hilbert space is an eigenvector of *some* Hermitian operator. Moreover this operator is easy to construct if you are given the fact that the state was once an eigenstate of something simple.

Comment: "Every vector in a Hilbert space is an eigenvector of some Hermitian operator." This is fascinating as well as puzzling. Is there any theorem illustrating this point? I said it's puzzling for the following reason.

Comment: Consider the double slit experiment. Let $|L\rangle$ and $|R\rangle$ be the states of a particle passing through the left and right slits, respectively. The, given what you said, $\alpha |L\rangle$ + $\beta |R\rangle$ (for non-zero, normalized $\alpha$ and $\beta$) would be an eigenstate of some observable.

Comment: If so, why people say as if this superposition state is 'mysterious' in the sense that it makes it tempting to say that the particle passes through both slits at the same time? If the superposition state is an eigenstate of some observable $O$--which I hope to be *somehow* related to the position observable---then can we not simply say that the particle has, say, a quasi-position corresponding to $O$?

Comment: Similarly, the Schrodinger's cat would also be in an eigenstate of *some* observable, in which case it seems that there is simply no mystery regarding the case; the cat is neither alive or dead, but in an eigenstate of some observable that may be somehow related to 'alive' or 'dead,' in a similar way that the z-spin is somehow related to the x-spin while being a totally different observable.

Comment: The upshot is, if *every* state is an eigenstate of some observable, then it is hard to understand why (at least some) people say that some cases of superposition are hard to understand. It looks like the only sensible thing to say about those cases is that those superposition states have some definite properties (associated with some complex observables) rather than having two or more orthogonal states at the same time or something like that. Is this something fair to say?

Comment: I agree. Every time someone says states in A have definite properties while states in B are superpositions of them, you can just as easily say states in B have definite properties while states in A are superpositions of them. Being entangled is an intrinsic property of a state but being in superposition is not.

Comment: But how do you prove that for any Hermitian A, a linear combination of the eigenstates of A is an eigenstate of another Hermitian B? Is this something easily shown?

Comment: Additionally, can we not say something similar about entanglement in that any system of two entangled particles whose composite state dwells on $H_{1} \otimes H_{2}$ is in an eigenstate of some observable $O_{1} \otimes O_{2}$ acting on $H_{1} \otimes H_{2}$? If so, isn't it that the *whole* entangled system always has some definite property?

Comment: As mentioned above, you just need to consider $\left | \psi \right > \left < \psi \right |$. It's perfectly fine to have trouble seeing why that's a proof but if so you should ask a separate question.

Comment: Oh, of course $|\psi\rangle \langle \psi |$ is Hermitian for any $| \psi \rangle$. Now I see it, thanks!